# Django app on Azure incorrectly loading static files from an Azure Blob

Tags: django, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-blob-storage, django-staticfiles

This Django app is deployed on Azure as an App Service its static and media files are stored in an Azure storage account - blob.

The project used to work well in the past, but something has changed and now the problem is as following.

Relevant part of the app settings file:

```
STATIC_URL = 'https://myappstorage.blob.core.windows.net/static/'
MEDIA_URL = 'https://myappstorage.blob.core.windows.net/media/'


STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
# any static paths you want to publish
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]
```

so one would expect that for example a favicon, which is in the root directory of the storage could be found on https://myappstorage.blob.core.windows.net/static/favicon and it is indeed!

But all static files that the app on azure tries to load it tries to load from

https://myappstorage.myappstorage.blob.core.windows.net/static/
(note the duplication of myappstorage), same for media files.

This results in no static files being applied to the page as they are being loaded from the wrong url. When I run the app locally, it works fine. I destroyed it and recreated it, no success. Now I have two copies running, one deployed through FTP and startup command and on using Github action. Still the same problem.

I have also tried little hack-ish workarounds in the setting file, with no success.

Answer (score 1):

Try with adding below in app setting

```
    DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'backend.custom_azure.AzureMediaStorage'
    STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'backend.custom_azure.AzureStaticStorage'
    
    STATIC_LOCATION = "static"
    MEDIA_LOCATION = "media"
    
    AZURE_ACCOUNT_NAME = "djangoaccountstorage"
    AZURE_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = f'{AZURE_ACCOUNT_NAME}.blob.core.windows.net'
    STATIC_URL = f'https://{AZURE_CUSTOM_DOMAIN}/{STATIC_LOCATION }/'
    MEDIA_URL = f'https://{AZURE_CUSTOM_DOMAIN}/{MEDIA_LOCATION}
```

refer this [document](https://medium.com/@DawlysD/django-using-azure-blob-storage-to-handle-static-media-assets-from-scratch-90cbbc7d56be) for more details